# Icons in webview displaying different on Kitkat version and also page loading issue.(eg.Menu icon)

Tags: web-applications, webview

```
Code for loading WebView. Screen appear white when loading on KitKat device.I used WebChromeClient in which override onProgressChanged() method.I used the following code.It works well on other devices greater than KitKat. Is there any solution for that.I read android developers doc but didn't get.Thanks.This is url private String url="https://xxxx.com/";



private void initWebview()
    {
        //Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        //Start this timer when you create you task
        //myTimer.schedule(new loaderTask(), 3000,1); // 3000 is delay in millies

        //webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this) {

              @Override
              public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
              //super.onPermissionRequest(request);
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
               @Override
               public void run() {
               if (request.getOrigin().toString().equals(url))
                 {
                  request.grant(request.getResources());
                  }else
                 {
                  request.deny();
                 }
                }
               });
             }
          }
       );

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                    handler.proceed();
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                            String description, String failingUrl) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "GOT Page error : code : " + errorCode + " Desc : " + description);
                    showError(OpenWebAppActivity.this, errorCode);
                    //TODO We can show customized HTML page when page not found/ or server not found error.
                    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
                }


                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    isPageLoadedComplete = true;
                    timeout=false;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
    }
```

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient
    {
        Context context;

```
    public MyWebChromeClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        timeout=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
        super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);
        getWindow().setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).
                setMessage(message).
                setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }).create();
        dialog.show();
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }
```

Code for loading WebView. Screen appear white when loading on KitKat device.I used WebChromeClient in which override onProgressChanged() method.I used the following code.It works well on other devices greater than KitKat. Is there any solution for that.I read android developers doc but didn't get.Thanks.

Comment: You need to show some effort. Show us your current code that fails, explain what you have tried, and exactly where you are stuck. By reading what you have written, we don't even know which language you are coding in...

Comment: Any solution please

Comment: I use webChromeClient but it open in Chrome window not in WebView.I used the if-else condition if device is less than KitKat then use WebChromeClient

Comment: give me solution it's on high priority

Comment: Show web chrome client code please

Comment: added code of web chrome client

Comment: Not needed  no longer, check the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Actual footage taken from the emulator under KitKat]

Firstly :

There is a big difference between WebViewClient and WebChromeClient regarding the manner of usage. Quoting from official docs:

**WebViewClient**

> /**
>        * Sets the WebViewClient that will receive various notifications and
>        * requests. This will replace the current handler.
>        *
>        * @param client an implementation of WebViewClient
>        * @see #getWebViewClient
>        */

**WebChromeClient**

> /**
>        * Sets the chrome handler. This is an implementation of WebChromeClient for
>        * use in handling JavaScript dialogs, favicons, titles, and the progress.
>        * This will replace the current handler.
>        *
>        * @param client an implementation of WebChromeClient
>        * @see #getWebChromeClient
>        */

So if your issue is just Kitkat and loading of webpage as it is, you don't need to use **WebChromeClient** at all!

So Fairly That can be the primary issue, meanwhile I couldn't test the webpage [xxxx](https://www.xxxx.com)

Because it was giving me error as I am behind a protection router, but I've tested google with image loaded already which worked properly and you can see in the image which is actually taken on KitKat emulator and it works just fine.

So basically I  just tuned up your code a little and here is the final code to use.

**GeneralWebViewClient**

```
public class GeneralWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private WebViewListener onWebViewListener;

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        if (onWebViewListener != null) {
            onWebViewListener.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Important to notice! This method must be used on in Lollipop and above versions because the old one is deprecated so we annotate it, but we have to use the old one for Pre-Lollipop devices
     * @param view
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        handler.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                String description, String failingUrl) {

        if (onWebViewListener != null) {
            onWebViewListener.onPageLoadingError(description, errorCode, false, null);
        }
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        if (onWebViewListener != null) {
            onWebViewListener.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Simple setter for the listener
     *
     * @param onWebViewListener
     */
    public void setOnWebViewListener(@Nullable WebViewListener onWebViewListener) {
        this.onWebViewListener = onWebViewListener;
    }


    /**
     * Add all needed logic to this method to release your used resources when the caller gets destroyed
     */
    private void releaseResources() {
        onWebViewListener = null;
    }


    /**
     * A class which handles a lifecycle events if attached. It is always a good idea to release resources when the caller gets destroyed, so this is a small tune up for that.
     */
    public class LifeCycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
        @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
        private void clean() {
            releaseResources();
        }
    }

    /**
     * So to make the code less in our main place, we just create  a set of needed callbacks to pass to the caller and just ignore the rest to keep main place clean and tidy
     * Important to notice the code {@code onPageLoadingError} which takes boolean argument {code sslError} ,hence indicating  whether it was an error from Sssl or no, and accordingly
     * {@code {@link SslErrorHandler}} can be null.
     */
    public interface WebViewListener {
        void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favIcon);

        void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url);

        void onPageLoadingError(String error, int errorCode, boolean sslError, @Nullable SslErrorHandler handler);
    }
}
```

**The Implementation of the GeneralWebViewClient class (MainActivity or the Activity you want to handle WebView Loading)**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GeneralWebViewClient.WebViewListener {

    private static final String TAG = "tag";
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        GeneralWebViewClient generalWebViewClient = new GeneralWebViewClient();
        generalWebViewClient.setOnWebViewListener(this);

        GeneralWebViewClient.LifeCycleObserver lifeCycleObserver = generalWebViewClient.new LifeCycleObserver();
        getLifecycle().addObserver(lifeCycleObserver);

        webView.setWebViewClient(generalWebViewClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favIcon) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        isPageLoadedComplete = true;
        timeout = false;
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageLoadingError(String error, int errorCode, boolean sslError, @Nullable SslErrorHandler handler) {
        if (sslError) {
            handler.proceed();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "GOT Page error : code : " + errorCode + " Desc : " + error);
            showError(OpenWebAppActivity.this, errorCode);
        }

    }

}
```

I really don't see the need of Chrome Client usage. If you need it, then in what case? Oh and just for safety purpose:

Don't forget to add Internet permission - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

Comment: my pleasure to do so

Comment: your code is working fine but there is some HTML page alignment issue in app.which minSdkVersion I set so there is no any issue arise

Comment: I chk with google link it works fine on 4.4 then is there is issue in HTML designing not from myside